# How to center four div's to the center of each side of the screen

Tags: html, css

I want to have four div's, one in the center along each side of the screen. So one div-element horizontally centered along the top of the screen, one on the bottom horizontally centered, and two, one one the left and one on the right side of the screen. Both vertically centered. How can I do this?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
            .boxes {
                position: absolute;
                width: 10px;
                height: 5px;
            }
            #top {
                top: 0;
                background-color: yellow;
            }
            #left {
                left: 0;
                background-color: green;
            }
            #right {
                right: 0;
                background-color: red;
            }
            #bottomMenu {
                bottom: 0;
                background-color: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div id="top" class="boxes"></div>          
            <div id="left" class="boxes"></div>
            <div id="right" class="boxes"></div>
            <div id="bottom" class="boxes"></div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

As it is now, I get both #top and #left in the top-left corner, #right in the top-right corner, and #bottom in the bottom-left corner.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform: translate` css property:

```
#top {
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  background-color: yellow;
}

#left {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  background-color: green;
}

#right {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  background-color: red;
}

#bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onwbw9k2/1/)**

### Or

Since, the boxes have fixed dimensions, you can use `margin: auto` and stretch the boxes.

```
.boxes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: auto;    /* added */
}

#top {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;right: 0;  /* to stretch */
  background-color: yellow;
}

#left {
  left: 0;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;  /* to stretch */
  background-color: green;
}

#right {
  right: 0;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;  /* to stretch */
  background-color: red;
}

#bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;right: 0;  /* to stretch */
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onwbw9k2/)**

Answer (score 4):

```css
.boxes {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
               
            }
            #left {
                top: calc(50% - 50px);
                background-color: yellow;

            }
            #bottom {
                left: calc(50% - 50px);
                background-color: green;
                bottom: 10px;
            }
            #top {
                right: calc(50% - 50px);
                background-color: red;
            }
            #right {
                bottom: calc(50% - 50px);
                background-color: blue;
                right: 10px;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <main>
            <div id="top" class="boxes"></div>          
            <div id="left" class="boxes"></div>
            <div id="right" class="boxes"></div>
            <div id="bottom" class="boxes"></div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this `transform`: `translate` `X` & `Y`

```
.boxes {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 5px;
   }
  #top {
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }

    #left {
        background-color: green;
        left: 0;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
                #right {
        background-color: red;
        right: 0;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
                #bottom {
        background-color: blue;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k6fhjLkx/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>
      #top {
        top: 0;
        position : fixed;
        left : 0;
        right : 0;
        background-color: yellow;
      }
      #left {
        left: 0;
        position : fixed;
        bottom : 0;
        top : 0;
        background-color: green;
      }
      #right {
        right: 0;
        background-color: red;
        position : fixed;
        bottom : 0;
        top : 0;
      }
      #bottomMenu {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        position : fixed;
        right : 0;
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer ...
    https://jsfiddle.net/rspc5zu1/

And here is code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <style>
                html,body{height:100%; position:relative;}
                .boxes {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 100px;
                    height: 120px;
                }
                #top {
                    top: 0;
                    background-color: blue;
                    left :0;
                    right:0;
                    margin:0 auto;
                }
                #left {
                    left: 0;
                    top:50%;
                    margin-top:-60px;
                    background-color: green;
                }
                #right {
                    right: 0;
                    top:50%;
                    margin-top:-60px;
                    background-color: red;
                }
                #bottom {
                    bottom: 0;
                    left:0;
                    right:0;
                    margin:0 auto;
                    background-color: blue;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <main>
                <div id="top" class="boxes"></div>          
                <div id="left" class="boxes"></div>
                <div id="right" class="boxes"></div>
                <div id="bottom" class="boxes"></div>
            </main>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea of doing it using `flex`

https://jsfiddle.net/e9qhxbrs/1/

```
    <body>
        <main class="main-container">
            <div id="top" class="boxes"></div> 
            <div class="side-boxes">
                  <div id="left" class="boxes"></div>
                  <div id="right" class="boxes"></div>
            </div>         
            <div id="bottom" class="boxes"></div>
        </main>
</body>
```

#### Css

```
 html{
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
 }

    body{

      position:relative;
      top:0;
      right:0;
      left:0;
      bottom:0;
      height:100%;
      width:100%;

    }

        .main-container{
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            right:0;
            left:0;
            bottom:0;
            z-index:1;
            background-color:transparent;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction:column;
            align-items:center;
            width:100%;
            justify-content:space-between;
        }
        .side-boxes{
          display:flex;
          justify-content:space-between;
          width:100%;
        }
        .boxes{
          background-color:#00f;
          height:100px;
          width:100px;
          border:2px solid #fff;
        }
        #top{
          background-color:red;
        }
        #left{
          background-color:lightgreen;
        }
         #right{
          background-color:green;
        }
           #bottom{
          background-color:blue;
        }
```